# Making mobile app for a responsive site

Tags: android, ios, firemonkey

I have a responsive web site and I need to make Android and iOS app for it to be published in each platform store so I am asking about the process/steps or the tool to do that. Can I use TWebBrowser component in Delphi XE 8 as a Firemonkey project to make these apps and make the site adjust its layout automatically according to the device used ? or there are other steps I should use ? or I should use different tool than Delphi ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm no web developer, but I know that making a website responsive is done on the server site. This way, if your mobile user opens Safari or Chrome, your site will be responsive and will adjust its limits to the device.

If you need to make native apps for each platform, you would have to replicate your website in native code and use API calls OR use whatever framework (like Firemonkey). Still, if you make an app with just a webview and load the website, it still won't be responsive.

Comment: Why if I used a webview it wont be responsive ?

Comment: No, it will just render the site as it is. The webview does not make the website responsive. If, however, the site is created responsive (from the server), then it will be responsive just as it is in Chrome, for example, or any other browser.

Comment: You can read about making a site responsive here https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/getting-started/your-first-multi-screen-site/responsive?hl=en

Comment: Yes I mean I already made the site responsive so if I display it in small width (mobile size) it should appear correctly

Comment: Well test it on a default browser (Safari or Chrome). If it appears responsive it will appear responsive in your webview. And that isn't hard to do at all